# Calculate P(B) Given Some Other Probabilities

Tags: probability

Is it possible to calculate P(B) if one knows P(A,B,C), P(A,B), P(B,C), P(A), and P(C)?

Comment: If the events are independent, you certainly can. Doesn't seem possible to do in the general without some additional knowledge, e.g. if $ P(A \cup C) = 1 $, then Alex R's answer applies. You could also deduce the answer in general given some other knowledge of the conditional probabilities.

Comment: You can even add P(A,C) to the list of probabilities given in the question - that still isn't enough information, in general, as can be seen fairly easily by experimenting with a Venn diagram. (I posted an answer illustrating this that assumed P(A,C) is given, because I misread the question as originally posted, then removed it after noticing my misread!)